# Bad Request error using passport-ldapauth

Tags: node.js, ldap, passport.js

1. I am trying to authenticate username and password using
   passport-ldapauth npm. while executing the below code I am always
   getting error as  Bad Request. Kindly help me what is wrong with my
   code.

   ```
   var express      = require('express'),
       passport     = require('passport'),
       bodyParser   = require('body-parser'),
       LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

   // Credentials from the free LDAP test server by LDAP Search

   var OPTS = {
     server: {

       url: 'ldap://54.227.207.201:389',
       bindDn: 'CN=simple One,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local',
       bindCredentials: 'password',
       searchBase: 'ou=passport-ldapauth',
       searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})'
     },
     usernameField: "CN=simple One,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local",
     passwordField: "password"
   };

   var app = express();

   passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

   app.use(bodyParser.json());

   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

   app.use(passport.initialize());


   app.use(passport.session());    

   app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}), function(req, res)  {  

   // you can refer code from here:https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth

     res.send({status: 'ok'});//will generate error 'Bad Request'

   });
      /*For more info:https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/issues/45*/
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`passport-ldapauth` returns bad request when [either username or password value is missing](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/blob/df03ccfe6542a7c9c3d9a1175fcadbd79bca5680/lib/passport-ldapauth/strategy.js#L133-L138). In your case this is probably because you have defined `usernameField: "CN=simple One,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local"`, ie. your login form should have the username to be used when logging in field with that name as mentioned in [readme](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/blob/0e7928ce4674e5662712b61fa49553ff6b223e5b/README.md#configure-strategy).

If your login form (or XHR post) sends the username in a field with name `weirdUsername`, eg. `<input type="text" name="weirdUsername"/>`, you would define `usernameField : weirdUsername`. The defaults, as again mentioned in the readme, are `username` for the username and `password` for the password.

Comment: I am trying to test passport-ldapauth in NodeJS using postman and I keep getting Bad request all the time. What am I doing wrong? I have followed the instructions mentioned in the Read me.

Comment: PS: I am a newbie with ldap authentication.

Comment: I'm using ldaps and my usernameField and passwordField are correctly filled in.

Comment: Make sure the request content type is "application/json".